# Trying to use matrices for Hadamard and Controlled Not gates

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I have the following simple quantum circuit:
[image: Simple_Circuit]

This outputs are 00 and 11 for the two qubits. Using matrices, I have applied the H gate to the first qubit (ket 0):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$

Is this right? Moreover, I don't understand how to apply the Controlled Not to to resulting matrix. I assume it's applied to a product basis state of the resulting:

$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

I would be grateful for any help on continuing this, and if anyone could point out if I am wrong with my previous calculations. I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application of Hadamard gate on the first qubit is correct.

Since CNOT is two qubit gate, it has to be described by matrix 4x4, so far you have only 2x2 matrix. However, there is a identity operator $I$ described by unit matrix on the second qubit. Hence the first step in you circuit can be described by matrix $H \otimes I$. Resulting matrix is of type 4x4. Now, you can apply CNOT gate.

So, first step is

$$
H \otimes I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Second step is CNOT gate
$$
CNOT= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The whole circuit is described by matrix

$$
CNOT(H \otimes I)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If you apply the circuit on input $|00\rangle$ you will get state

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This is so-called Bell state $\beta_{00}$. If you set inputs  $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$, you will get different Bell states.

---

**EDIT: a manual how to compute tensor product mechanically**

Based on comments below, here is a manual how to computer tensor product:

[image: Tensor product]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am confused as to why CNOT is a unitary matrix; isn't it defined $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Also, for the first step, where did the matrix from my earlier calculation go? What is $H⊗I$ and how does it create $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 1&0&-1&0\\ 0&1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Sorry for the typo in CNOT, just corrected.

Comment: $H \otimes I$ is so-called tensor product. In simple words, you put matrix $I$ on each position in $H$ and multiply it by element in $H$. Be aware that tensor product is not generally commutative operation. See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: Thank you, that is starting to make more sense to me, but what is matrix $I$. I don't understand how it is obtained from the second qubit. Could you write out the maths as to explain how you got to matrix $H⊗I$

Comment: @TomAllen: Matrix $I$ is unit matrix $I = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. If there is no gate on a qubit, it means there is $I$, i.e. nothing is done (like empty instruction on classical computer). Please see comment above with link to Wikipedia on how to compute tensor product mechanically.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't come across tensors before, so the wikipedia article looks a tad daunting. Could you explain it simply like if I were to explain matrix multiplication to a baby, lol, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}3&4\\ 6&-2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}5&9&2\\ 0&7&8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\left(5\right)+4\left(0\right)&...&...\\ 6\left(5\right)+\left(-2\cdot 0\right)&...&...\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: See *picture manual* in the answer :-)

Comment: Brilliant! My maths now checks out. My last question (I promise): what's the significance of the coefficient $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ before the output matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Also, does $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ mean that the output is both $00$ and $11$ i.e. quantum superposition?

Comment: Yes, the superposition is composed of states $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$. Value $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is normalization coefficient since any quantum states has to satisfy that it is described by a unit vector in space $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: I am understanding, but having trouble wrapping my head around this normalisation coefficient. Could you explain it further, or, if it is too complex, refer me to a reading which explains it simply and concisely? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Each vector describing quatum state $|\psi\rangle = (a_1, a_2 \dots a_n)$ has to be described by unit vector, i.e. $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2} =1$. Moreover, $|a_i|^2$ is a probability that superposition $|\psi\rangle$ in collapses to state $i$ after measurement.

Comment: Okay, so the vector requires a magnitude 1 (which makes sense given that the superposition collapses into a definite state of 0 or 1 - when observed). But I am still unsure of how this relates to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Is this coefficient the probability of collapse into state $i$?

Comment: The probability is square of the coefficient.

Comment: Ooh, very nice. So $|a_i|$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the square of that is the probability (or 0.5 - 50%)? Thank you for all your help. I have to admit, I have always loved dealing with matrices and vectors, but never found a really cool use for them and so lost interest. But with quantum computing I am learning something new and cool everyday. Thanks again!